# Electrum setup problem

Tags: wallet, electrum, public-key

I was trying to install electrum, and for some reason, I wanted to see what multisig wallet was, and now I'm stuck on the master public keys window, I can't cancel and select standard wallet. Every time I open the installer it asks me to input the master public keys.

Comment: I deleted it and reinstalled it and didn't work maybe I didn't I it correctly.....still trying to set me up with multisig.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem today. You need to close Electrum, delete the Electrum folder, and start Electrum again. This will "reset" the installation.

The Electrum folder is `~/.electrum` on Linux and Mac. On Windows it should be `Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets` (it's shown without slashes on the official Electrum website but this should probably be where it is). You might need to show hidden files in order to see it on Windows.

*Note that this folder contains your wallets so if you have existing ones, you'll want to back them up first.*